# C++ Equivalent of Java Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, c++, object, hashmap

In Java you can create a Map that maps String to Generic Object types that can be explicitly casted to other classes. Is there any nice way of imitating this functionality in C++?

Comment: There's a map in c++11/14, std::map. please check if it could meet your requirement.

Comment: and also [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: i think op is talking about a class Object that can accept any kind of object...not about the data container collection Map

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). Or perhaps for a plain old `void*`. Difficult to tell without knowing how you plan to use this thing.

Comment: This is really a lot more open ended of a question than it might appear at first glance.  There's no _direct_ correlate in C++ to Java `Map<String, Object>`, because the C++ typesystem itself is too different in fundamental ways.  For example, `Map<String,Object>`, being a java generic, is really fundamentally `Map<Object,Object>` with syntactic sugar; and is a base class.  `std::map<std::string, Foo>` in C++ is a first level object, which genuinely has std::string keys.  Also, there's no `Object` equivalent in C++, though there are weak types/wrappers.

Comment: ...if there's a _particular_ itch you're scratching with `Map<String,Object>` in Java, there's likely at least one particular way to scratch that itch in C++; _generally_ though there's at least 5 different approaches to "mimic" this in C++ that I can think of off the top of my head (and they're all different).

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you can use **std::map<std::string, std::any>**.

Answer (score 1):

Being a quite strongly typed language, C++ does not have a "Generic Object Type". It surely has associative containers: [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) (a flavour of binary tree) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) (a flavour of hash table). Which is better depends on the use case, and often can't be decided without profiling.

The closest thing to a generic object I can think of is a common ancestor for all the objects that might be put in this map. Here the idea is to create a class hierarchy with dynamic polymorphism, and to store the objects in the map as pointers cast into that common ancestor.
The ideal design would make casting of these objects back to their derived class unnecessary. If instead such cast is required, one will have to use a `dynamic_cast` (and possibly check that it succeeded).

It is mandatory to store *pointers* to the objects in the map, as opposed to the objects themselves. Otherwise, of the objects one tries to insert into the map, only the common ancestor part would be stored, and the polymorphism would be lost. It also needs to be decided whether the map owns the objects or not (no garbage collection here). If not, simple pointers may work. If the map owns the objects, I would recommend storing them wrapped in "unique pointers" (`std::unique_ptr`).
Wrapping up:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr<>, std::make_unique()
#include <iostream>

class NotSoGenericClass {
    public:
  virtual ~NotSoGenericClass() = default;
  virtual std::string name() const
    { return "NotTooGenericClass()"; }
};

class EvenLessGenericClass: public NotSoGenericClass {
  int fValue = 0;
    public:
  EvenLessGenericClass(int value): fValue(value) {}
  virtual std::string name() const override
    { return "EvenLessGenericClass(" + std::to_string(fValue) + ")"; }
  int value() const { return fValue; }
};

int main() {
  //
  // map holding (and owning) "not so generic objects"
  //
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<NotSoGenericClass>> allObjects;

  //
  // populate it
  //
  allObjects["any"] = std::make_unique<NotSoGenericClass>();
  allObjects["six"] = std::make_unique<EvenLessGenericClass>(6);
  allObjects["one"] = std::make_unique<EvenLessGenericClass>(1);

  std::cout << "Object 'six' says: " << allObjects["six"]->name() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Now dumping all " << allObjects.size() << " objects:";
  for (auto const& keyAndObject: allObjects) {

    auto const& key = keyAndObject.first;
    auto const* object = keyAndObject.second.get();

    //
    // base class interface is always available:
    //
    std::cout << "\n[" << key << "] " << object->name();

    //
    // object-specific one requires a cast:
    //
    auto const* lessGen = dynamic_cast<EvenLessGenericClass const*>(object);
    if (lessGen) std::cout << " (value is " << lessGen->value() << ")";

  } // for
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
} // main()
```

On my platform, this code (using C++14) emits:

```
[one] EvenLessGenericClass(1) (value is 1)
[six] EvenLessGenericClass(6) (value is 6)
[any] NotTooGenericClass()
```

(also illustrating the meaning of "unordered" in the map name).
This example was compiled with `g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -o test.exe test.cpp` (GCC 6.4.0).